# Trigger no actualiza en DynamoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, trigger, aws, dynamodb

Tengo una tabla en DynamoDB llamada "Settlement" la cual, entre otras muchas cosas, me guarda 2 campos que al finalizar una actualizacion **tienen** que ser iguales, en caso de que no, también aplica a la ayuda de la pregunta.
[image: Columnas]
La funcion es que tengo una lambda padre, que crea toda la fila con sus parametros, y con ella la columna *Chunks_To_Processed*, que lleva por default la cantidad de lotes que la lambda hija va a procesar. *Chunks_Processed* se crea inicialmente con 0. La lambda hija procesa ciertos lotes que son enviados por la lambda padre, y con forme se procesen, se actualiza esta columna, en caso de que de error, actualiza otra (Pero para esta consulta no importa esa otra); entonces tengo un trigger que se ejecuta sobre esta tabla de "Settlement" pero solo hace cosas cuando se modifica

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    for records in event['Records']:
        if records['eventName'] == "MODIFY":
            if records['dynamodb']['NewImage']['Type'] != {"S": "Trigger" }:
                print("Valores anteriores", records['dynamodb']['NewImage']['Type'])
                records['dynamodb']['NewImage']['Type'] = {"S": "Trigger" }
            #if records['eventName']['dynamodb']['NewImage']['Chunks_Processed'] ==  records['eventName']['dynamodb']['OldImage']['Chunks_To_Processed']:
                #update_Main(records['eventName']['dynamodb']['OldImage']['UUID'])

                print("Valores nuevos", records['dynamodb']['NewImage']['Type'])
                print(event)
    return
```

Entonces no se si es conveniente hacer el proceso habitual de update_item de dynamodb? Porque mi jefe me dijo que el propio event puede hacer la modificación. Y es que creo que me lo dijo porque de esa forma no dispara este trigger, en cambio de la forma que actualmente lo hago, si lo dispara.

EDITO:
Trato con lo que mi jefe me dice `records['dynamodb']['NewImage']['Type'] = {"S": "Trigger" }` y en la consola si me aparece que...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al ver la BD sigue saliendo el mismo valor de *LIQ*. Ojo que este campo actualmente no es el final, es solo por fines practicos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuantos puntos de mi curso de inteligencia artificial voy a ganar sii resuelvo el problema?? Aqui ayudamos a resolver problemas de codigo, no a hacerte la tarea... Reformula tu pregunta con muestras de codigo que has tratado y donde te has quedado atascado

Comment: @LuisFelipe Sii logras resolver el problema, te pago $200 por paypal... Porque la solución que tengo ahorita dudo que sea eficiente, funciona, pero una vez me regañaron por hacer ese proceso

Comment: no gracias manito, te cito diciendo "Cuantos puntos de mi curso de inteligencia artificial voy a ganar sii resuelvo el problema??".

Comment: @LuisFelipe Sii lo se... Así de inmaduro eres pensando que te ibamos a hacer tu tarea sin siquiera haber intentado algo antes

Comment: yo nunca he publicado mi tarea manito, vi como le respondiste así a otro usuario y decidí hacerte lo mismo.   Aprende a ser más humilde, si no vas a responderle mejor ni le comentes.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478833/como-seria-el-codigo-en-python-para-resolver-este-enunciado-con-que

Comment: @LuisFelipe Peor... Pero sii te hace sentir bien poner esos comentarios en mis preguntas, dale... Me da exactamente igual, voy a seguir comentando lo mismo cuando crea útil

Comment: tus respuestas de ese tipo no son nada utiles manito